# Finding roots to equation using a modulo-divided numpy.poly1d in python

Tags: python, numpy, modulo, equation-solving

I've created a polynomial object using `numpy.poly1d` and some arbitrary coefficients `(a,b,c)` so that I can find the roots of the equation `ax^2 + bx + c = y0` at a given `y0`. In principle, that can be done fairly easily by calling the method `root` of the `poly1d` object.

The only issue is that the actual equation I am trying to solve is the same as the one written above, but modulo-divided by 2π which corresponds to finding x when the polynomial modulo-divided by 2π equals to `y0`, (or find `x` for `y = (ax^2 + bx + (c-yo)) [2*pi]`)

However, it seems that I can't apply this modulo operator to a `poly1d` object.

Is there a way of doing that using NumPy?

Here are some lines of code:

```
import numpy as np

def x_to_y(x,a,b,c):
    return (a*x**2 + b*x + c) % (2*np.pi)

def y_to_x(y0,a,b,c):
    a,b,c = coeffs
    eq = np.poly1d([a,b,c]) % (2*np.pi) # throws an error, can't apply % operation on poly1d object
    return (eq-yo).roots
```

Comment: Can you use `np.mod` instead of `%` ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can use `np.mod` instead of `%`.
The only problem being that `np.mod` returns an array in that case, not a poly1d object.

Comment: Exactly, and I do need to call the attribute <poly1d_obj>.roots to find the solutions of the equation

Answer (score 0):

Actually managed to bodge it by simply adding 2kπ to the 0th order term of the polynomial, and sweeping over a few values of k till I get a root that is comprised within the correct bounds.

Not ideal but it works. Still open to clever ways of doing it though!